# How can i use OR condition in match?

Tags: dsl, karate

I am trying to execute this code:

```
When def responseFromAuthenticatedExternalWSO2Gateway = call read('classpath:examples/Services/InvokeAuthenticatedQantasExternalWSO2Gateway.feature') {'domain': '#(domain)' , 'basepath': '#(basepath)' , 'path': '#(path)' , 'externalGatewayResponse': '#(externalGatewayResponse)' , 'method': '#(requestMethod)' , 'accessTokenforSandbox': '#(accessTokenforSandbox)' }

Then retry until responseFromExternalWSO2Gateway.responseStatus == 404 || responseFromExternalWSO2Gateway.responseStatus == 200
```

But this '||' OR condition is not working with match eventhough '&&' AND condition works.

Is there any workaround for this ?

Comment: Done. Can I get some help with this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, the `retry until` is not designed to work with a request made in a `call`. It has to be declared *before* you do `* method`.

Also I have no idea what you mean by "'&&' AND condition works"

Please make the question more clear or follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Thanks for that. My question is : I am able to use '&&' with retry until like this : * retry until responseFromExternalWSO2Gateway.responseStatus == 404 && response.documentation_url = 'https://developer.github.com/v3' , but i am  not able to use '||' with retry until like this:  retry until responseFromExternalWSO2Gateway.responseStatus == 404 || response.documentation_url = 'https://developer.github.com/v3'

Comment: As per what i understand && is used for checking an 'AND condition' and || is used for checking 'OR Condition'.

Comment: my requirement is to put a 'OR Condition' with retry until

Comment: I am not sure how to achieve that

Comment: @SnehaShukla your question does not make any sense, `||` should work normally which is why I am saying you are doing something wrong. so unless you follow the instructions in the link I posted, I cannot help you.

Comment: Okay let me try it again . Thanks @Peter Thomas